# Segfault on jump/branch

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, gdb, mips, buffer-overflow

I am currently playing around with heap exploitation and got a segfault which I don't understand at all. I would expect a segfault due to my heap overflow somewhere but I don't understand why it is happening in that line (as gdb tells me):

```
bnez   $v0, free+240
```

The only reason why a segfault could make sense here is if free+240 would not be accessible. But there is executable code at this position and v0 is zero anyway, so the branch should never be taken in the first place. Nevertheless, the segfault happens:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                                                                                                                 0x77f0ca94 in free () from target:/lib/libc.so.0`

Does someone has an idea why this can happen?

Comment: Verify actual `$pc`, also maybe check preceding instruction(s) in case the fault is misreported. Consult kernel log, as that also might have register dump.

Comment: That's correct, what you've shown (and that register state) doesn't explain the segfault, so this isn't a [mcve].  I haven't used GDB to debug a real MIPS (mostly just played some with MARS), but I know real MIPS has branch-delay slots, so I wonder if that instruction in the delay slot could be faulting?  But no, you said v0=0 so it won't be taken.  Does GDB tell you whether the segfault was from code-fetch or data load, and if so what address was being accessed?  Is 0x77f0ca94 the address of the bnez?  Or of its target, or of the branch-delay slot?

Comment: @Jester Thanks for the tips! So it could be that gdb tells me a wrong line for the segfault for example? Is there a better to verify the $pc than using "info register $pc"  in gdb?

Comment: Consult syslog in case your kernel prints message there. Might need to run it outside of gdb for that (at least on my system). Could also insert a breakpoint a few instructions earlier and then single step.

Comment: @Jester thanks I'll give the syslog a try. Single stepping is something I already tried and it always segfaults at the branch instruction.

Comment: @Peter 0x77f0ca94 is the address of the bnez instruction. Maybe it is actually something MIPS specific although I am just emulating it with QEMU. I will dig into this a bit more, thanks.